# Data share with service between unrelated components is not working

Tags: angular

I have built a shared data service which should send dropdown choice from 1 component to the component which is its sibling's grandchild. but I cant get it to work.

Shared service:

```
@Injectable()
export class LiveDataService {
    private subject: BehaviorSubject<MyData> = new BehaviorSubject<MyData>(null);

    public currentValue(): MyData {
        return this.subject.value;
    }

    public changeValue(data: MyData): void {
        this.subject.next(data);
    }

    public getValue(): Observable<MyData> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Sending Component

```
@Component({
})
export class MainComponent {
    constructor(private liveDataService: LiveDataService) {}

    onDropdownChange() {
        this.liveDataService.changeValue({id: event.value} as MyData);
    }
}
```

Receiving Component

```
@Component({
})
export class AnotherComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private liveDataService: LiveDataService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.liveCutoffData.getValue().subscribe((myData) => {
            this.myData = myData;
            this.doSomething(this.myData);
       });
    }
}
```

my.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MainComponent,
        AnotherComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        ...
    ],
    providers: [
        LiveDataService,
    ],
  })
export class MyModule {
}
```

From logs I can see that MainComponent is sending changes. However AnotherComponent is not recieving those changes and nothing is happening

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve] ?

Answer (score 1):

Change `@Injectable()` to `@Injectable({  providedIn: 'root'})` on the service which ensures it will be registered as a singleton service with angular.

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class LiveDataService {
  // ...
```

See also [Providing a singleton service](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#providing-a-singleton-service)

Comment: can we make more than one service as `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})`...?

Comment: @ganesh045 - Short answer: yes. Long answer: `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})` ensures that injected instances of `LiveDataService` are all the same instance. You can use this attribute on any "service" type that is injected where you want a single instance (singleton pattern).

Comment: thank you for your explanation that means to say, we can use more than one service as singleton in Our App...?

Comment: @ganesh045 - correct, you can add this to every service in your app if you wish.